# Experiences of using JSCH Java ssh library

Tags: java, jsch

I am in the process of choosing a Java SSH libary. I am leaning towards JSCH, but before I make a final decision I wanted to hear other people's expereinces of the library, good or bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brand new version of Jsch just went up on github. It is a vast improvement to the existing library in many ways. Check out the README on the site and the comprehensive javadoc for more information. https://github.com/vngx/vngx-jsch

Answer (score 1):

I am using this library in my projects, ant it is works fine and it is easy to use. Also it has not only SSH but and SCP where you can transfer files.